# div with no content and percentage height is not appering

Tags: html, height, background-image, percentage

I have a div with no content, a background image and the width and height should be percentages.
It does not appear with no content.

how can I make it appear?

**html**

```
<div id="adelediv">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   #adelediv {
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url(hello.gif);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

+ when i put it in pixels it works but i do not want it in pixels i want it in percents

Comment: When you inspect the elements is it in the source? Also, curious, why the requirement for height: 100%.

Comment: Maybe it's because one of the surrounding elements has `undefined` height and thus percentage fails. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Its parent div must have specific height  width to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css min-height property to set a min height of the div element.Right now parent element has not height.That's why its not showing

```
     html, body
     {
    height: 100%;
     }
     #adelediv {
           float: left;
           height:100%;
           width: 100%;
           background-image: url(hello.gif);
           background-size: cover;
        }
```

https://www.your-plugin.com

Comment: This just makes it 100px high

Comment: hi ,percentage in height will not work unless you specify a specific height for any parent in the loop.So give a height to parent element.html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

Answer (score 1):

Give the Position
attribute in the style class

```
Position : absolute;
```

Comment: Then you can adjust the height  and width percentage as you want.